# python csv reader escaping escapechar itself - no error is produced

Tags: python, csv

I would like to use at python csv to read a row which is escaped by % into a list. When there is a wrong input there should be an error thrown (or at least it should be possible to detect the wrong input).

So a correct input of `'%%a%,b,c'` leads to a list of `['%a,b', 'c']`. A wrong input of `'%a%b,c'` now leads to a list of `['a,b', 'c']` but should raise an error because the first escapechar % is not escaping itself.

Currently my code for a minimum working example is this where `tag_names` is the resulting list:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

tag_string_wrong = '%a%,b,c'
tag_string_correct = '%%a%,b,c'

csv_stream = StringIO(tag_string_wrong)

reader = csv.reader(csv_stream, delimiter = ',', escapechar = '%', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, strict=True)

tag_names =  next(reader, [])
```

I hope somebody can help me.

---

**Edit**:
With the comments I found out that I misunderstood the concept of escaping at python csv. But I found out that when I transform `tag_string_wrong` back with `csv.writer` the result is not the same as the input. (at `tag_string_correct` the result is the same)

The code below produces for `tag_string_wrong` the string `a%,b,c` at the output but in my point of view it better should raise an error because it cannot be transformed back to the same value as the original input.

Do I miss something that the output is not the same anymore than the input?

---

code to transform and transform back:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

tag_string_wrong = '%a%,b,c'
tag_string_correct = '%%a%,b,c'

input = tag_string_wrong

# read in data

print('input = {}'.format(input))

csv_stream = StringIO(input)

reader = csv.reader(csv_stream, delimiter = ',', escapechar = '%', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, strict=True)


tag_names =  next(reader, [])

print('tag_names = {}'.format(tag_names))

# read back values

csv_stream_in = StringIO()

writer = csv.writer(csv_stream_in, delimiter = ',', escapechar = '%', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, strict=True)

writer.writerow(tag_names)


print('output = {}'.format(csv_stream_in.getvalue()))
```

Comment: Maybe the question is also related to [this bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue12178) but I am not sure about that.

Comment: _should raise an error because the first escapechar % is not escaping itself_ could you elaborate on this?

Comment: In the "wrong" string you are escaping `a` and then `,` and that's what you get. In the "correct" string, you get the escaped escape char `%` and then `,` just like in the other string, and just like expected. What am I missing here?

Comment: @destoryer Thank your for your question and yes, you are right. I guess I more missunderstood here the concept of _escaping a character_. I understood it  in that case and would like to have it that to write the char `%` I have to escape again with `%%`. A single `%` without a character to escape (`%` or `,`) should throw an error.
I guess to solve the problem I have to dive into regex.

Comment: Glad to have helped.